# Private functions in Laravel 5 service containers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm building an app with Laravel 5.1 using my own service providers to separate some business logic, but I can't seem to find a way to acces other methods of the service provider from within itself.

Using the function name tries to look for something in the namespace App\Providers and there's no $this because it's singleton pattern, so how can I do it? Does it have to "use" itself?

I also don't want an external helper as this function would be specific to this service.

Answer (score 0):

Simply enough it can be done using self::method() or static::method() but your method has to be declared as static.